# UWP ListView padding and ScrollView height

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, scrollview

I've got a `ListView` where I've got a collection of something like post it notes.

I've set that all `ListView` elements have `padding="0,0,0,-170"` so I could stack notes one on another only to be able to see their Header (title) and also seeing last note fully. It works great but the only problem is that when I stack more notes one on another I comes to a moment that bottom of my note (by bottom I mean everything lower than header) is missing from `ListView`.

The idea is just to make it scrollable further (like adding 170px that I've took with padding), but yet I don't know how to change scroll height. Im open for any ideas, maybe there's some workaround this.

Here's the code:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,-170"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Note">
        <StackPanel Height="202" Width="200" Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF320000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF935920" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC59564" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock Name="header" Text="{Binding header}" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="30" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="#FFD6B900" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
            <TextBlock Name="content" Text="{Binding content}" Margin="5,0,5,5" Height="135" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="header"/>
            <TextBlock Name="date" Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringFormatConverter}}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="20" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Black" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image: Link to screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after I've wrote that post I came to solution :)

The only thing I had to do was to set a proper padding on ListView.

So if in **ItemContainerStyle** I've set -170px padding I just had to add +170px to **ListView**

Funny I couldn't get it before that.